# Without using a library, how to build a Blazor navbar dropdown control

Tags: drop-down-menu, blazor, navbar

A dropdown menu Item should be easy, but I've tried Bootstrap and it doesn't work.
It should be as easy as having a navbar button with the dropdown links (buttons) hidden until the main button is clicked.
I am trying to find a life-cycle event to trigger to make the child buttons appear.
Yes, I'm very new to Blazor.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Polite]  Without the right skill set you probably don't.  They are not as easy to code as it would at first seem.  Either use one of the pure CSS versions, or use a library one.  For pure CSS versions see something like https://1stwebdesigner.com/pure-css-navigation-menus/.  Or have a go and ask a question when you get stuck.